# Publishing iOS App, error signing in to iTC: "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect."

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am new to iOS development. I developed an app. I have developer account but when I want to publish my app on iTunes. My credentials are not working.

There is error when I attempt to sign in to iTunes Connect:

> "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect".

Comment: Please Read this and try again [Apple Help Center](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25671432#25671432)

Comment: There are 3 iOS programs. 1) Free but can't build to device or submit to App Store. 2) $99 a year allows to build to 100 test devices and Submit to App Store. 3) ?(Can't remember price but it's not cheap) This is the Enterprise program that allows you to build to a load of test devices. When you signed up did you give them any money?

Comment: you have to subscribe the iOS Developer Program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to have signed up for the iOS developer program (which costs $99 a year) to access iTunes connect and be able to submit apps.
Are you sure your developer program is current and not expired?

Additionally, if you've signed up on behalf of a company, only an agent or admin can enable your access to iTunes connect.

**edit**

To find out what programs you have signed up for:

1. Go to developer.apple.com
2. Click on Member Center
3. Login
4. Click on "Programs & Add-ons" to see what developer programs you have signed up for.

Comment: how I know my account expired or not and signed up with ios developer program. Please help!

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: @user3185059 it's simple did you give them any money and how much?

Comment: As I mentioned, the iOS developer program costs $99 a year. You can make the payment via credit cards, debit cards etc!

Comment: I've signed up, paid and get the same error with the account that create our company account so this answer doesn't work for all.

Comment: I get this error too and i have an individual subscription.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add another answer where itunesconnect cannot be enabled. An enterprise application cannot have itunesconnect and hence it cannot leverage the TestFlight facilities.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

"**Important: As a member of the Apple Developer Enterprise Program, you don’t have an iTunes Connect account or the ability to distribute your app for beta testing using iTunes Connect.**"

Under the section: "Testing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps"

Answer (score 1):

Create at least one additional iTunes Connect user for your organization.

1. Invite a Person to Your Team
       https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#invitations
2. Invitee should accept you invitation.
3. Once invitaion accepted, you can signin to iTunes Connect.