# Issue connect to itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am new to itunes connect, and i do have a apple developer profile account, but when i use the same credentials it pops me a error message "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect"

Can any one please help suggest how to get itunes activated, i need to chcek the number of app downloads, app status, review etc for my app.

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem with the actual agent. They just created their account a few days ago and can't log in to iTC at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at the answer here :
[Publishing iOS App, error signing in to iTC: "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155960/publishing-the-app)

The agent user(for your company) should be able to signup for itunes connect and send you the invitation on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are getting the error, it could be that you have an Apple Enterprise account not a developer account.

Use the phone numbers [here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php) to talk to a representative from apple on how to create a dev account.

Long story short, they will tell you enterprise accounts are for in house development only, not for app store.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

"**Important: As a member of the Apple Developer Enterprise Program, you don’t have an iTunes Connect account or the ability to distribute your app for beta testing using iTunes Connect.**"

Under the section: "Testing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps"